# Basic "Raw" Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, http

I have a serverside function:

```
string foo(string input_string);
```

for example:

```
foo("bar") returns "baz"
```

and have wrapped this function into a HTTP server such that:

```
POST /foo HTTP/1.1
...

bar
```

will return:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...

baz
```

ie a POST request with the input string as the HTTP Message Body will return the output string as the HTTP Message Body of the 200 OK.

Now in my javascript on the web page I have two functions:

```
function sendFoo(input_string)
{
   ??? // should asynchronously start process to POST input_string to server
}

function recvFoo(output_string)
{
   ...
}
```

When I call sendFoo I would like the POST to be made asynchronously to the server and later when the response is received I would like recvFoo called (perhaps in another thread or whatever) with the Message Body of the 200 OK.

How do I implement sendFoo above?  I am currently using jQuery, but a solution in pure javascript is ok too.  (I can also modify the server if need be?)

**Solution**:

```
function sendFoo(input_string)
{
   $.ajax({ url: "/foo", type: "POST", data: input_string, success: recvFoo });
}
```

Comment: you can use Jquery ajax via post right ?

Comment: Are you still having difficulties?

Comment: trying out suggested solutions shortly, starting with yours.  in chrome i notice that it trys to send an "OPTIONS" request first.  Also if the URL is bad I get no error message, but I guess that is unavoidable.

Comment: you can add to `ajax` a callback for error, `success: recvFoo, error: errorFunction`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to fallback to classic `JavaScript`

```
$.ajax({
        url:"URL of foo...",
        type: "POST",
        data: "what ever",
        success: recvFoo
       });
```

Or the `post` option:

```
  $.post('The url of foo', {input_string : 'bar'}, recvFoo);
```

Comment: Why not just use `jQuery.post()` for this?

Comment: @Jivings. I like the `ajax`, it's more readable for me. do you want me to add the `post` option?

Comment: I used your ajax solution, and it works fine.  Only change was replacing "function(data) { recvFoo(data); }" with just "recvFoo"

Comment: @Jivings, look at his comment on his question, now he wants an error callback, which is unavailable with `post`, I like `ajax`...

Comment: Actually, not true. You can use the error callback with the `post` function.

Answer (score 6):

[`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) object's [`open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29) method allows you to specify the HTTP method while the [`send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#send%28%29) method allows to specify the message body, e.g.

```
var xhr = ... // obtain XMLHttpRequest object
xhr.open('POST', '/foo'); // HTTP method and requested URL.
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      recvFoo(xhr.responseText); // Will pass 'baz' to recvFoo().
  }
};
xhr.send('bar'); // Message body with your function's argument.
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery post will do the job:

```
$.post('foo.html', {'varname' : 'bar'}, function(data) {
  recvFoo(data);
});
```

Very well laid out question, thanks.